# GUI password prompt: `Incorrect password`

Tags: linux, debian, passwords

I installed Debian Jessie without a desktop environment and installed i3wm afterwards. If I start an application which requires administrative privileges inside i3wm other than by running the command in a terminal (e.g. through dmenu) a GUI password prompt pops up saying:

```
APPLICATION needs administrative privileges. Please enter your password.
```

However, no matter what I put in there and no matter whether I chose `Save for this session` or `Save in the keyring` it always displays `Incorrect password ... try again.`

What do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by opening `gksu-properties` and setting `Authentication mode` to `sudo` instead of `su`.